# Check checkbox with data map jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, autocomplete

I use a form that is dynamically fed with autocomplete field.
when I select a result in the autocomplete field that filled the form.
In this form I have a checkbox, and they do not check up when I select the result of the autocomplete field

`$('#dispositif').val([item.idDispositifPart])` is the id to my checkbox field.

Thanx to all

```
                success : function(donnee){
                response($.map(donnee, function(item){
                    return {
                        label: ucwords(item.nom) + ' ' + ucwords(item.prenom) + ' (' + item.codeRH + ')',
                        value: function (){
                            $('#leCollaborateur').show();
                            $('#codeRH').val(item.codeRH);
                            $('#codeRH_b').val(item.codeRH);
                            $('#civilite').val(item.idCivilite);
                            $('#civilite_b').val(item.idCivilite);
                            $('#sexe').val(item.idSexe);
                            $('#sexe_b').val(item.idSexe);
                            $('#nom').val(ucwords(item.nom));
                            $('#nom_b').val(ucwords(item.nom));
                            $('#nomJF').val(ucwords(item.nomJeuneFille));
                            $('#nomJF_b').val(ucwords(item.nomJeuneFille));
                            $('#prenom').val(ucwords(item.prenom));
                            $('#prenom_b').val(ucwords(item.prenom));
                            $('#dateNaissance').val(dateFR(item.dateNaissance));
                            $('#dateNaissance_b').val(dateFR(item.dateNaissance));
                            $('#dispositif').val([item.idDispositifPart])
                            $('#dispositif_b').val([item.idDispositifPart]);
                            $('#cuid').val(item.CuID);
                            $('#typeContrat').val(item.idTypeContrat);
                            $('#typeContrat_b').val(item.idTypeContrat);
                            $('#dateArrivee').val(dateFR(item.dateArrivee));
                            $('#dateArrivee_b').val(dateFR(item.dateArrivee));
                            $('#bande').val(item.idBande);
                            $('#bande_b').val(item.idBande);
                            $('#site').val(item.idSite);
                            $('#site_b').val(item.idSite);
                            $('#departement').val(item.idDepartement);
                            $('#departement_b').val(item.idDepartement);
                            $('#fonction').val(item.idFonction);
                            $('#fonction_b').val(item.idFonction);
                            $('#responsable').val(item.idResponsable);
                            $('#responsable_b').val(item.idResponsable);
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check/uncheck a checkbox you need to set the `checked` property. So assuming `idDispositifPart` has a boolean value try

```
$('#dispositif').prop('checked', item.idDispositifPart)
```

Comment: Thanks Arun but not work :(
When I change the value in the autocomplete, there are no changes to the checkbox field

Comment: @FrenchFlair what is the value in `item.idDispositifPart`

Comment: ex: value="a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"4";}"